# Why won't replace work with my regex object when test does?

Tags: javascript, regex

I feel silly asking this because I'm betting the answer is staring right at me but here goes.

I'm taking a string from the CSS style textDecoration and trying to remove the underline portion of the string (and any whitespace around it). It returns true when I run test() but when I do the replace method the string is unaltered. Help?

My code:

```
    textDecoration = function(str) {
            var n_str = str + '|/\s' + str + '|/\s' + str + '/\s|' + str + '/\s';  
            var nre = new RegExp(n_str, "g");
            debug_log('Found or not: ' + nre.test(txt));
            txt.replace(nre, '');
            debug_log('Result: ' + txt);
            debug_log('-----------------------');
    }

    var txt = "underline";
    debug_log('-----------------------');
    debug_log('Starting String: ' + txt);
    textDecoration("underline");
    txt = "underline overline line-through";
    debug_log('-----------------------');
    debug_log('Starting String: ' + txt);
    textDecoration("underline");
    txt = "overline underline line-through";
    debug_log('-----------------------');
    debug_log('Starting String: ' + txt);
    textDecoration("underline");
    txt = "overline line-through underline";
    debug_log('-----------------------');
    debug_log('Starting String: ' + txt);
    textDecoration("underline");
```

Output:

[image: The output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replace()` returns a new string with the replaces and don't change the actual string. You should do something like:

```
var newString = txt.replace(nre, '');
debug_log('Result: ' + newString);
```

Answer (score 1):

`test` returns a boolean. `replace` returns a new string. It does not alter the string.

Also, your regular expression is quite odd. Applying `str = "underline"`, you will get:

```
/underline|\/sunderline|\/sunderline\/s|underline\/s/
```

which does not match whitespaces, but `"/s"`.

Comment: I'm new to regex. I was assuming that would match "underline", " underline ", " underline", and "underline ". Am I wrong?

Comment: In your string you gave the RegExp constructor, the s was escaped (to s) and before it s stands a slash. You need to escape the backslash before the s in your string to make it a whitespace metacharacter for the regexp. Also, you shouldn't delete the blanks on both sides of "underline" :-)

Comment: Oh, good call on not deleting both blanks! If it's the middle one then I would have a problem. I'll do some more searching and figure out how to escape those properly. Thanks a lot for the help!